# User Activity Report using Calendar Table

Tags: mysql

I am driving nuts to get what it was supposed to be a simple query done. I have the following table:

Daily Check-In Table: **tbl_checkin** (uniqueid, userid, clock)

Sample data:

```
1   1   7/25/2014 12:00:00 AM
2   1   7/25/2014 2:37:05 PM
3   2   7/25/2014 3:22:29 PM
```

Calendar Table: calendar (datefield)

Sample data contains dates from 2012 to 2050 (i.e. 1/1/2012 12:00:00 AM, etc..)

I am looking to get this result:

```
Date:     Count:
Jul 21    0
Jul 22    0
Jul 23    0
Jul 24    0
Jul 25    3
Jul 26    0
Jul 27    0
Jul 28    0
```

My query specifies a date range. In the above sample, I specified 1 week but I could specified any date range. The closest I got with the query is this:

```
SELECT 
 date_format(calendar.datefield, '%b %e') AS clockdate,
COUNT(*) AS total
FROM tbl_checkin RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(tbl_checkin.clock) = calendar.datefield)
WHERE (calendar.datefield BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE('2014-07-21')) FROM tbl_checkin) 
AND (SELECT MAX(DATE('2014-07-28')) FROM tbl_checkin))
GROUP BY clockdate;
```

The result I get is this:

```
Date:     Count:
Jul 21    1
Jul 22    1
Jul 23    1
Jul 24    1
Jul 25    3
Jul 26    1
Jul 27    1
Jul 28    1
```

For some reason I get 1 on the dates I have nothing. A user could have multiple entries in a single day. Does anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `count(*)` is used, rows where `tbl_checkin.clock is null` is also counted as 1 (because of the `right join`). We just need to replace `count(*)` with `count(tbl_checkin.clock)`:

```
SELECT 
 date_format(calendar.datefield, '%b %e') AS clockdate,
 COUNT(tbl_checkin.clock) AS total
FROM tbl_checkin 
RIGHT JOIN calendar ON DATE(tbl_checkin.clock) = calendar.datefield
WHERE calendar.datefield BETWEEN '2014-07-21' AND '2014-07-28'
GROUP BY clockdate;
```

Comment: Thank you Fabricator for all your help, it works now :), thanks